# Does JOINs works in Amazon CloudSearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, solr, amazon-cloudsearch

I want to shift from **Apache Solr** to **Amazon CloudSearch**. Currently, I am using JOINs between two cores lets say. Does *JOINs* works in Amazon CloudSearch?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to join across what are known as *domains* in CloudSearch -- that is, a separate search index with a different schema. There is no way to do that.

Comment: Thank you @alexroussos. Is grouping on any field is possible in AWS cloud search like Solr?

Comment: I think the analog here would be _facets_ in CloudSearch http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/faceting.html

Comment: There is a huge difference between grouping and facets. I mean real grouping.